# Is there an open-source API gateway that offers rate limiting for WebSockets?

Tags: open-source, websocket

I have been looking for an open-source API gateway that not only supports WebSockets like the [Kong API gateway](https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.4.x/proxy/#proxy-websocket-traffic) but also provides frame-based rate limiting for WebSocket requests. After googling for a while, I know that the [WSO2 API manager](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/05/introducing-websocket-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/#:%7E:text=WebSocket%20API%20throttling), but I'd like to know if other alternatives exist, I also found that the [AWS API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-protect.html) provides this feature, but I'd prefer an open-source solution.